# How to move the panels in Spyder 4.0?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

Spyder 4.0 just released and I am not able to move the panels for my desired layout.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enable panel moving by switching off the option in `View > Lock panes and toolbars`, or pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F5</kbd>. From there, you can drag around panes as you wish.

When you're done, you can lock them again with the same process. If you want to save the current layout, you can use <kbd>Alt+Shift+S</kbd>. Also, in the `View > Window Layouts` menu, you can see and launch preset layouts that mirror other editors such as R Studio and Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

press **CTRL+SHIFT+F5** or goto **view => lock panes and toolbars** & than turn it off... thn move ur panel